# Overriding a Django app url to make it Non-accessible

Tags: django, url, django-urls

I'm using *userena* for handling the users' profiles. I created an app that override some of userena **views** and **urls**.
In particular I've created two different signup forms, so now I have two separate urls:

```
url(r'^signup/customer/$',....
url(r'^signup/owner/$',...
```

The original userena signup form was accessible at `r'^signup/$'`.

**Question**: How do I override the *userena* original **signup url** in order to make it unavailable?
The original url should not be accessible to anyone, so I guess Django should show a 404 page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your root `urls.py` conf, just override the url which you want to disable and direct it to Django 404 (page not found) view:

```
from django.views.defaults import page_not_found

url(r'^signup/$',
    page_not_found,
    name='userena_signup'),
```

Comment: Thanks! Any idea of why Django shows me the "Oops! This link appears to be broken." instead of a "Page not found (404)"?

Answer (score 1):

If you are already overriding some views and URLs, you could override the signup URL with a view that just returns a 404 response.